# how to simplify str replace in php

Tags: php

I have some content like this i need to replace {{values}}.How can i do it in php.How can i replace all strings in one function in PHP ?

```
$mail ="Dear {{ name }} ,
    Your warranty is going to expired in {{ count }} days. Please kindly renew it trhough your dashboard or drop a check. For further details call our sales dept at 1231212121212
    Confirmation id: {{ confid }}
    Warranty Period: {{ Effctivedate }} - {{ Expirydate }}
    Property Address: {{ Address }}";
```

**PHP**

```
echo str_replace('{{ name }}','Test',$mail);
```

Comment: And where is the problem ? `str_replace (` **mixed $search , mixed $replace** , `mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

Comment: its working fine only for the name i need to replace `{{ confid }}` & `{{ Effctivedate }} - {{ Expirydate }}` and `{{ Address }}` in one function how can i do that ?

Comment: [**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) -> **mixed** $search , **mixed** $replace <- Means it also takes `arrays` as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace` can be used with arrays.

```
echo str_replace(Array("{{ name }}", "{{ confid }}", ...), Array($name, $confid, ...), $mail);
```

Done.

Comment: No problem :-) You can vote up the answer and mark it as solution if you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        $mail ="Dear #NAME# ,
            Your warranty is going to expired in #count# days. Please kindly renew it trhough your dashboard or drop a check. For further details call our sales dept at 1231212121212
            Confirmation id:  #confid#
            Warranty Period: #Effctivedate# - #Expirydate#
            Property Address:#Address#";

    $mail= str_replace("#NAME#",$Name,$mail);
    $mail= str_replace("#confid#",$confid,$mail);
    $mail = str_replace("#Effctivedate#",$Effctivedate,$mail);
    $mail = str_replace("#Expirydate#",$Expirydate,$mail);

ecoh $mail;
```